# Selecting multiple value in CAutoComplete field

Tags: php, yii

I have given a CAutoComplete field in my form, and it's suggesting as per my query, now what I need is, after selecting a item from the suggestion box, if I put a comma and go for another item suggestion, then suggestions are working fine as per I have coded it like that, but selecting item is removing 1st item selected in the field and take it's place. What I want is, the items should be stay there as an input in the field.

[image]

after 1st select the field contains Nokia 100. Now after that if I put a ',' and again type something, then suggestion comes, and I also can select from them..

[image]

Selecting the new product is removing the previous one. How to get it like: Nokiaa 100, Micromax..., ... in the input box. Here's my code

```
<?php $this->widget('CAutoComplete', array(
                            'name'=>'ListModel[indexIds]',
                            'id'=>'input-box',
                            'attribute'=>'search',
                            'url'=> $this->createAbsoluteUrl('list/suggestions'),
                            'value'=>'',
                            'minChars'=>2,
                            'scroll'=>false,
                            'resultsClass'=>'searchAutoComplete ac_results',
                            'htmlOptions'=> array('class'=>"searchClickClear",'id'=>'select'),
                            'methodChain'=>'.result(function(){$("form#search-form").submit();})'
               )); ?>
```

this is the input field

public function actionSuggestions()
        {

```
        if(isset($_GET['q']) && ($keyword=trim($_GET['q']))!=='')
        {
            $what = $_GET['q'];
            $what = explode(',', $what);
            if(is_array($what))
                $what = end($what);
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->select = array("product_name");
            $criteria->condition = "product_name LIKE '%{$what}%' AND tagged = 1";
            $criteria->group = "product_name";
            $products = Production::model()->findAll($criteria);
            $result = array();

            if(count($products) > 0)
            {
                foreach($products as $p)
                    $result[] = $p->product_name;

                echo implode("\n",$result);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the suggestion part.

Answer (score 0):

The default CAutoComplete cannot handle this at the moment but there is an [extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/multicomplete/) that extends it's behaviour as a wrapper for CJuiAutotComplete.
It works like the jQuery UI multitagging demo.

Found this by typing your question into google and the first answer that came up was this one.